# Mysql row duplication with count

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table **Call_hist** structure is like this

```
  Mobile       Name    Amount     Day   
  --------------------------------------
1234567890    Pra        70       Sunday   
9876543210    Spe        63       Sunday   
9876543210    Spe        380      Sunday   
1234567890    Pra        888      Monday   
9876543210    Spe        70       Monday   
9876543210    Spe        630      Monday
```

I want to sort these data's like below

```
  Mobile       Name       Day    Reps
  ------------------------------------------
  1234567890  Pra       Sunday    1
  9876543210  Spe       Sunday    2
  1234567890  Pra       Monday    1
  9876543210  Spe       Monday    2
```

Please assist me .

Comment: So, by day, and then by number of reps?

Comment: What is the PRIMARY KEY on this table?

Comment: Primary Key Is ID- by day or by number no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you're after this...

```
SELECT mobile
     , name
     , day
     , COUNT(*) reps 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY mobile
     , name
     , day 
 ORDER 
    BY day DESC -- THERE ARE OTHER WAYS TO SORT DAYS OF THE WEEK
     , reps;
+------------+------+--------+------+
| mobile     | name | day    | reps |
+------------+------+--------+------+
| 1234567890 | Pra  | Sunday |    1 |
| 9876543210 | Spe  | Sunday |    2 |
| 1234567890 | Pra  | Monday |    1 |
| 9876543210 | Spe  | Monday |    2 |
+------------+------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to aggregate by mobile, name, and day, and count the distinct amounts:

```
SELECT
    Mobile,
    Name,
    Day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT amount) AS Reps   -- see below **
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Mobile,
    Name,
    Day;
```

** If the same amount appearing more than once should also be counted, then just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: `...ORDER BY...`

Comment: How it consider which day it is? @Tim Biegeleisen